# switch break malfunction in c++ how?

Tags: c++, odbc, switch-statement, break

I'm trying to run the following code:

```
SQLSMALLINT** column_types = new SQLSMALLINT*[*ColumnCount];


void** ColumnsData = new void*[*ColumnCount];

SQLINTEGER** rowLengths = new SQLINTEGER*[*ColumnCount];

int limit = *ColumnCount;
for(int i=0;i<limit;i++)
{
    column_types[i] = new SQLSMALLINT();
     SQLColAttribute(hStmt,i+1,SQL_DESC_TYPE,NULL,NULL,NULL,(SQLPOINTER)column_types[i]);
     SQLSMALLINT type = *column_types[i];
     switch(type)
     {
     case SQL_CHAR:

             ColumnsData[i] = new SQLCHAR**[*RowCount];
             for(int l=0;l<*RowCount;l++)
             {
                 ((SQLCHAR**)ColumnsData[i])[l] = new SQLCHAR[512];
             }

             rowLengths[i] = new SQLINTEGER[*RowCount];

             SQLBindCol(hStmt,i+1,SQL_CHAR,ColumnsData[i],512,rowLengths[i]);
            break; //<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

     case SQL_VARCHAR:

             ColumnsData[i] = new SQLCHAR**[*RowCount];
             for(int l=0;l<*RowCount;l++)
             {
                 ((SQLCHAR**)ColumnsData[i])[l] = new SQLCHAR[512];
             }

             rowLengths[i] = new SQLINTEGER[*RowCount];

             SQLBindCol(hStmt,i+1,SQL_VARCHAR,ColumnsData[i],512,rowLengths[i]);
             break;

     case SQL_LONGVARCHAR:

             ColumnsData[i] = new SQLCHAR**[*RowCount];
             for(int l=0;l<*RowCount;l++)
             {
                 ((SQLCHAR**)ColumnsData[i])[l] = new SQLCHAR[512];
             }

             rowLengths[i] = new SQLINTEGER[*RowCount];

             SQLBindCol(hStmt,i+1,SQL_LONGVARCHAR,ColumnsData[i],512,rowLengths[i]);
             break;

     case SQL_WCHAR:

             ColumnsData[i] = new SQLWCHAR**[*RowCount];
             for(int l=0;l<*RowCount;l++)
             {
                 ((SQLWCHAR**)ColumnsData[i])[l] = new SQLWCHAR[512];
             }

             rowLengths[i] = new SQLINTEGER[*RowCount];

             SQLBindCol(hStmt,i+1,SQL_WCHAR,ColumnsData[i],512,rowLengths[i]);
             break;

     case SQL_WVARCHAR:

             ColumnsData[i] = new SQLWCHAR**[*RowCount];
             for(int l=0;l<*RowCount;l++)
             {
                 ((SQLWCHAR**)ColumnsData[i])[l] = new SQLWCHAR[512];
             }

             rowLengths[i] = new SQLINTEGER[*RowCount];

             SQLBindCol(hStmt,i+1,SQL_WVARCHAR,ColumnsData[i],512,rowLengths[i]);
             break;

     case SQL_WLONGVARCHAR:

             ColumnsData[i] = new SQLWCHAR**[*RowCount];
             for(int l=0;l<*RowCount;l++)
             {
                 ((SQLWCHAR**)ColumnsData[i])[l] = new SQLWCHAR[512];
             }

             rowLengths[i] = new SQLINTEGER[*RowCount];

             SQLBindCol(hStmt,i+1,SQL_WLONGVARCHAR,ColumnsData[i],512,rowLengths[i]);
             break;

     case SQL_DECIMAL:

             ColumnsData[i] = new SQL_NUMERIC_STRUCT[*RowCount];

             rowLengths[i] = new SQLINTEGER[*RowCount];

             SQLBindCol(hStmt,i+1,SQL_DECIMAL,ColumnsData[i],512,rowLengths[i]);
             break;

     case SQL_NUMERIC:

             ColumnsData[i] = new SQL_NUMERIC_STRUCT[*RowCount];

             rowLengths[i] = new SQLINTEGER[*RowCount];

             SQLBindCol(hStmt,i+1,SQL_NUMERIC,ColumnsData[i],512,rowLengths[i]);
             break;

     case SQL_SMALLINT:

             ColumnsData[i] = new SQLSMALLINT[*RowCount];

             rowLengths[i] = new SQLINTEGER[*RowCount];

             SQLBindCol(hStmt,i+1,SQL_SMALLINT,ColumnsData[i],512,rowLengths[i]);
             break;

     case SQL_INTEGER:

            ColumnsData[i] = new SQLINTEGER[*RowCount];

             rowLengths[i] = new SQLINTEGER[*RowCount];

             SQLBindCol(hStmt,i+1,SQL_INTEGER,ColumnsData[i],512,rowLengths[i]);
             break;

     case SQL_REAL:

             ColumnsData[i] = new SQLREAL[*RowCount];

             rowLengths[i] = new SQLINTEGER[*RowCount];

             SQLBindCol(hStmt,i+1,SQL_REAL,ColumnsData[i],512,rowLengths[i]);
             break;

     case SQL_FLOAT:

             ColumnsData[i] = new SQLREAL[*RowCount];

             rowLengths[i] = new SQLINTEGER[*RowCount];

             SQLBindCol(hStmt,i+1,SQL_FLOAT,ColumnsData[i],512,rowLengths[i]);
             break;

     case SQL_DOUBLE:

             ColumnsData[i] = new SQLDOUBLE[*RowCount];

             rowLengths[i] = new SQLINTEGER[*RowCount];

             SQLBindCol(hStmt,i+1,SQL_DOUBLE,ColumnsData[i],512,rowLengths[i]);
             break;

     case SQL_BIT:

             ColumnsData[i] = new SQLCHAR[*RowCount];

             rowLengths[i] = new SQLINTEGER[*RowCount];

             SQLBindCol(hStmt,i+1,SQL_BIT,ColumnsData[i],512,rowLengths[i]);
             break;

     case SQL_TINYINT:

             ColumnsData[i] = new SQLSCHAR[*RowCount];

             rowLengths[i] = new SQLINTEGER[*RowCount];

             SQLBindCol(hStmt,i+1,SQL_TINYINT,ColumnsData[i],512,rowLengths[i]);
             break;

     case SQL_BIGINT:

             ColumnsData[i] = new SQLBIGINT[*RowCount];

             rowLengths[i] = new SQLINTEGER[*RowCount];

             SQLBindCol(hStmt,i+1,SQL_BIGINT,ColumnsData[i],512,rowLengths[i]);
             break;

     case SQL_BINARY:

             ColumnsData[i] = new SQLCHAR**[*RowCount];
             for(int l=0;l<*RowCount;l++)
             {
                 ((SQLCHAR**)ColumnsData[i])[l] = new SQLCHAR[512];
             }

             rowLengths[i] = new SQLINTEGER[*RowCount];

             SQLBindCol(hStmt,i+1,SQL_BINARY,ColumnsData[i],512,rowLengths[i]);
             break;

     case SQL_TYPE_DATE:

            ColumnsData[i] = new SQL_DATE_STRUCT[*RowCount];

             rowLengths[i] = new SQLINTEGER[*RowCount];

//>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
             SQLBindCol(hStmt,i+1,SQL_TYPE_DATE,ColumnsData[i],512,rowLengths[i]);
             break;

     case SQL_TYPE_TIME:

             ColumnsData[i] = new SQL_TIME_STRUCT[*RowCount];

             rowLengths[i] = new SQLINTEGER[*RowCount];

             SQLBindCol(hStmt,i+1,SQL_TYPE_TIME,ColumnsData[i],512,rowLengths[i]);
             break;

     default:

             break;

     }
}
```

When it gets into case SQL_CHAR and gets to break it jumps to case SQL_TYPE_DATE before the SQLBindcol call, how is it possible, is that a malfunction or am i doing something wrong here since break supposed to exit the switch

Comment: Check for an extra `}` in the actual code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest commenting out all of the other switch cases apart from `SQL_CHAR` and seeing what happens. If the debugger steps into commented out code you must have optimisation on. If that behaves, add the other cases back one at a time and see when the problem re-appears. That will narrow down the cause of the problem.

Comment: The debugger steps into commented code, but i have optimization at c/c++ Disabled(/Od) Could you explain please that in visual studio where one can set optimisation one?

Comment: Sometimes close visual studio, get tea/scream, breathe deeply then do a rebuild sorts it.

Comment: "optimisation one" was a typo I meant "optimisation on"

Comment: well sadly it didn't do the trick for me :( what should i do then?

Comment: We'd need to see the compiler and linker command line for the active configuration

Comment: i take back my last words, i restarted the computer and now it works flawlessly... i'm speechless.

Comment: note to self: when you answer to a MSVC user, always suggest to reboot first :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume that you're seeing this behavior in some sort of debugger, AND I'm going to assume that you've built an optimized build. In that case all you're seeing is the optimizer reusing code - optimizers generally make it somewhat difficult to debug, so just make an unoptimized build.

If you really haven't built with optimization enabled, the first thing I would try is doing a full clean/rebuild (still without optimization) to make sure you have a consistent base test to work from.

Comment: Thank you all for the answers, i am using visual studio debugger, and i am making an unoptimized debug build already, i have also tried a full clean/rebuild, still with no luck.

Comment: try what @doctorlove suggested, then

Comment: Is it possible that the changes made to the compiler due to a performance analysis before can cause this? Changes because of i get warnings like:
(warning LNK4075: ignoring '/INCREMENTAL' due to '/PROFILE' specification 
)

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are saying so because of examining the code throught a debugger. Try to disable optimisation during compilation.